# How can PostScript run a url?

Tags: postscript

PostScript would be much more useful if a run command were provided for Google Drive. One possibility would be some scheme to run a url instead of a local file. Can JavaScript dhelp with this? Alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

The standard allows for such a thing to be added. Using the `(%device%path) file` syntax would be the way to do it but it would need to be implemented in the interpreter and I'm not aware of any that do this. There are security concerns of course, but it would be covered by the existing `-DSAFER` option which disables the `file` operator.

Comment: Can the JavaScript "escape" command (which converts a string into a url) be of any help here?

Comment: Possibly, but I'm not entirely sure how to go about it. I know you can embed JavaScript in PDF. It's possible you could get something to work using PDF as the outer "frame".